# Proof verification: $d$ and $\tilde{d}$ are topologically equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Given $X = (0,1]$ a metric space with $\tilde{d}$ defined as $$\tilde{d}(x,y) = \bigl|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\bigr| \ \  \text{for} \ \ x,y \in X$$

I'm trying to prove that  $\tilde{d}$ and $d$ the standard metric on $(0,1]$ are topologically equivalent, using the open sets criteria and would like to know if it's correct.

**Proof:** 
$U$ is open in $(X,\tilde{d}) \implies U$ is open in $(X,d)$

Let $x \in U$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x,\tilde{d}) \subseteq U$

If $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x,\tilde{d})$ which means $ \tilde{d}(x,y) =\bigl|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\bigr| = \bigl|\frac{y-x}{xy}\bigr| = \frac{|x-y|}{|xy|} < \epsilon$ and that's equivalent to $d(x,y) = |x-y| < |xy|\epsilon$, then $y \in U$

Therefore, for  any $x \in U$ we can find an epsilon $\tilde{\epsilon} = |xy|\epsilon$ such that: $y \in B_{|xy|\epsilon}(x, d) \implies y \in U$

$\Longleftarrow$

Similarly, If $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x,d)$, it follows that $d(x,y) = |x-y| < \epsilon$ which is equivalent to $\tilde{d}(x,y) =\bigl|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\bigr| < \frac{\epsilon}{|xy|}$

Therefore, for  any $x \in U$ we can find an epsilon $\tilde{\epsilon} = \frac{\epsilon}{|xy|}$ such that: $y \in B_{\frac{\epsilon}{|xy|}}(x, \tilde{d}) \implies y \in U$

Comment: There is a mistake right here $d(x,y) = |x-y| < |xy|\epsilon$, then  $\tilde{\epsilon} = |xy|\epsilon$. You have to gain an $\tilde{\epsilon}$ such that it does not depend on $y$.

Comment: Yes, that's true. "$y \in B_{|xy|\epsilon}(x, d)$" doesn't make sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is not valid. You cannot make $\tilde {\epsilon}$ depend on $y$. Suppose $B_{\epsilon} (x,\tilde {d}) \subset U$ with $0<\epsilon <1$. Choose $ \tilde {\epsilon} >0$ such that $\tilde {\epsilon} < \min \{\frac x 2,\frac {\epsilon x^{2}}2\}$. (Note that $x >0$. This is crucial here).  Then $|y-x| < \tilde {\epsilon}$ implies $|\frac 1 y -\frac 1 x|=\frac {|y-x|} {xy} <\epsilon$ because $\epsilon xy >\epsilon x(x-\tilde {\epsilon})=\epsilon x^{2}-\epsilon x{\tilde {\epsilon}} >2\tilde {\epsilon}-\epsilon x{\tilde {\epsilon}} >{\tilde {\epsilon}}$ (since $\epsilon x <1$). Hence $B_{\tilde {\epsilon}} (x,d) \subset B_{\epsilon} (x,\tilde {d}) \subset U$.  I leave the other part to you.

Comment: Thank you. I am still trying to work out your answer. If you don't mind, could you please explain more how you picked such $\tilde {\epsilon}$?

Answer (score 2):

There is a fault in your proof. Kindly see the proof below for the other side

\begin{align}\bar{d}(x,y)<r_2 &\iff \left| \dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}  \right| <r_2 \iff \dfrac{1}{x}-r_2<\dfrac{1}{y}<\dfrac{1}{x}+r_2\\&
\iff \dfrac{1-x r_2 }{x}<\dfrac{1}{y}<\dfrac{1+xr_2 }{x}
 \end{align} 
Choose $r_2<\dfrac{1}{x},$ then
\begin{align}
 \dfrac{1-x r_2 }{x}<\dfrac{1}{y}<\dfrac{1+xr_2 }{x}&\iff  \dfrac{x }{1+x r_2}<y<\dfrac{x }{1-xr_2}\\& \iff - \dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1+x r_2}<y-x<\dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1-xr_2}.
 \end{align} 
As $r_2\to 0,$ then $\dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1+x r_2}\to 0$ and $\dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1-xr_2}\to 0.$ Hence, $\forall \, r>0,$ and $\forall \,x\in (0,1],$ there exists $r_2\in (0,1]$ such that $r_2<(r/2x^2).$ So, 
\begin{align}
 y-x<\dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1-xr_2}<x^2 r_2 <\dfrac{r  }{2}<r.
 \end{align} 
Also, \begin{align}
r_2<\dfrac{r}{2x^2}\iff -r_2>-\dfrac{r}{2x^2}\iff -x^2 r_2>-\dfrac{r}{2}.
 \end{align}
But, $r_2\in (0,1]\implies r_2>-\dfrac{1}{2x},$ implies $x r_2>-\dfrac{1}{2} \iff 1+x r_2>\dfrac{1}{2}\iff \dfrac{1}{1+x r_2}<2.$ Hence,
\begin{align}
y-x> - \dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1+x r_2}>-\dfrac{r}{2(1+x r_2)} > -\dfrac{2r}{2}=-r
 \end{align} 
Hence, we have that 
\begin{align}
-r=-\dfrac{2r}{2}<-\dfrac{r}{2(1+x r_2)}< - \dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1+x r_2}<y-x<\dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1-xr_2}<x^2 r_2 <\dfrac{r  }{2}<r.
 \end{align} 
Therefore, \begin{align}
|x-y|<r \iff d(x,y)<r
 \end{align}
And you are done. Kindly get back if you have some questions. Remember that they don't necessarily need to have the same radius.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! :) It's super helpful. I just got abit stuck in the part you applied the Archimedean principle. How does it relate to $\dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1+x r_2}$ and $\dfrac{x^2 r_2 }{1-xr_2}$ tending to zero, as $r_2\to 0$?

Comment: @mike: You can either use the fact that $r_2\to 0$ or Archimedean principle to establish your claim. Anyway, I'll edit for clarity.